# firePress only once on a SAPUI5 button

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to execute a click event on a button. I can do this using `firePress` however this is a toggle button so it gets stuck in a loop.

```
onPromotionEditPressed: function(){
    this.byId("__xmlview1--tablePromotion-btnEditToggle").firePress();
    return;
}
```

The function never gets to the return so it never stops. How can I ensure this runs only once?

Comment: Are you sure it is keep looping? The event is triggered only one time when you call the `firePress()`. Just check how many times the `onPromotionEditPressed()`  is called? If `onPromotionEditPressed()` is looping then ofcourse you need to fix the `onPromotionEditPressed()` event.

Comment: May be you need to change the `pressed` property of the `toggleButton` control.

Comment: `var oBtn = sap.ui.getCore().byId("YourBtnID");
if (oBtn) {
  oBtn.firePress();
  oBtn.setPressed(!b.getPressed())
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SAP` already has an element for Toggle Button so maybe have a look at the full example here **[Toggle Button Preview](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ToggleButton/preview)**

```js
onPress: function(oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.getSource().getPressed()) {
    new sap.m.MessageToast.show(oEvent.getSource().getId() + " Pressed");
  } else {
    new sap.m.MessageToast.show(oEvent.getSource().getId() + " Unpressed");
  }
},
```

```html
<HBox>
  <ToggleButton id="tablePromotion" text="Pressed" enabled="true" pressed="true" press="onPress" />
</HBox>
```

OR

If you are trying to call the fire event from another method in the **same controller** assuming "tablePromotion" is the ID for the button called without the __xmlview1--...

```js
this.getView().byId("tablePromotion").firePress();
```

OR

Called from a **different controller** as:

```js
sap.ui.controller("namespace.Controllername").onPress();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to make sure it only runs once.

this is described and explained in [david walsh blog](https://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions).

```
function once(fn, context) { 
    var result;

    return function() { 
        if(fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        }

        return result;
    };
}

// Usage
var canOnlyFireOnce = once(function() {
    console.log('Fired!');
});
```